# Lightning Connect - connect to another org

Tags: lightning-connect

In [Summer 15 release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_summer15_release_notes.pdf) I found an an article about 
*Access Data Across Multiple Organizations with the Lightning Connect Salesforce
Connector*. However, I cannot find any step-by-step resource related to Lightning Connect org to org connecting.

When setting the `External Data Source`, what should the URL to another org look like? Also, should `Administration Username` be a username from another org with some special permissions?

[image: External Data Source]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to be in Salesforce Pre-Release Org for the same .In my Summer 15 trial org ,I can see the configuration as shown in below screenshot .You will select Type as Lightning Connect:Salesforce

[image]

Also Please create an Auth Provider of type salesforce as shown in below screenshot

[image]